# OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float in python

Tags: python, overflow, factorial

I tried to calculate poisson distribution in python as below:

```
p = math.pow(3,idx)
depart = math.exp(-3) * p 
depart = depart / math.factorial(idx)
```

idx ranges from 0

But I got `OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float`

I tried to convert depart to `float` but no results.

Comment: Factorial gets *really* large, *really* fast

Comment: What is the value of idx when you hit this error?

Comment: When you wish to compute a factorial, compute it's logarithm instead

Answer (score 43):

Factorials get large *real fast*:

```
>>> math.factorial(170)
7257415615307998967396728211129263114716991681296451376543577798900561843401706157852350749242617459511490991237838520776666022565442753025328900773207510902400430280058295603966612599658257104398558294257568966313439612262571094946806711205568880457193340212661452800000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

Note the `L`; the factorial of 170 is still convertable to a float:

```
>>> float(math.factorial(170))
7.257415615307999e+306
```

but the next factorial is too large:

```
>>> float(math.factorial(171))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

You *could* use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html); calculations will be slower, but the `Decimal()` class can handle factorials this size:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(math.factorial(171))
Decimal('1241018070217667823424840524103103992616605577501693185388951803611996075221691752992751978120487585576464959501670387052809889858690710767331242032218484364310473577889968548278290754541561964852153468318044293239598173696899657235903947616152278558180061176365108428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
```

You'll have to use `Decimal()` values throughout:

```
from decimal import *

with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 32  # desired precision
    p = ctx.power(3, idx)
    depart = ctx.exp(-3) * p 
    depart /= math.factorial(idx)
```

Comment: What is the large number class in Python called? because `170!` is well above the limits of a 64-bit integer. I assume the type is coerced to that? If so, why is the `L` still appended to the end?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Python long integers are only limited by OS memory allocation. The `L` signifies we moved beyond the maximum C integer size for the platform (64-bit in my case) to show long integers are being used; the transition is automatic. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: Ahh, I see. Most other languages have `BigInteger` or something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When `idx` gets large either the `math.pow` and/or the `math.factorial` will become insanely large and be unable to convert to a floating value (`idx=1000` triggers the error on my 64 bit machine). You'll want to not use the math.pow function as it overflows earlier than the built in `**` operator because it tries to keep higher precision by float converting earlier. Additionally, you can wrap each function call in a `Decimal` object for higher precision.

Another approach when dealing with very large numbers is to work in the log scale. Take the log of every value (or calculate the log version of each value) and perform all required operations before taking the exponentiation of the results. This allows for your values to temporary leave the floating domain space while still accurately computing a final answer that lies within floating domain.

```
3 ** idx  =>  math.log(3) * idx
math.exp(-3) * p  =>  -3 + math.log(p)
math.factorial(idx)  =>  sum(math.log(ii) for ii in range(1, idx + 1))
...
math.exp(result)
```

This stays in the log domain until the very end so your numbers can get very, very large before you'll hit overflow problems.

Comment: I think `3 ** idx  =>  math.log(3) * math.log(idx)` should be `3 ** idx  =>  math.log(3) * idx`

Answer (score 5):

Try using the decimal library. It claims to support arbitrary precision.
`from decimal import Decimal`

Also, you don't need to use `math.pow`. `pow` is in-built.

Comment: Hi guys 

I tried to use decimal or scipy but i got 

ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

the same error for decimal

Comment: what version are you running? `decimal` library is supposed to be standard for all. perhaps you have deleted it. re-install python and it will fix it. as for scipy, it is a third-party package, so you'll have to download it from scipy.org

Comment: I am going to use poisson like this:     depart = depart + Poisson(3) so that inter-arrival times are selected by Poisson. but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The `scipy` module could help you.

[scipy.misc.factorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html) is a factorial function that can use the gamma function approximation to calculate the factorial, and returns the result using floating points.

```
import numpy
from scipy.misc import factorial

i = numpy.arange(10)
print(numpy.exp(-3) * 3**i / factorial(i))
```

Gives:

```
[ 0.04978707  0.14936121  0.22404181  0.22404181  0.16803136  0.10081881
  0.05040941  0.02160403  0.00810151  0.0027005 ]
```

There is also a [module to calculate Poisson distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html). For example:

```
import numpy
from scipy.stats import poisson

i = numpy.arange(10)
p = poisson(3)
print(p.pmf(i))
```

Gives:

```
[ 0.04978707  0.14936121  0.22404181  0.22404181  0.16803136  0.10081881
  0.05040941  0.02160403  0.00810151  0.0027005 ]
```

Comment: +1 for `scipy.stats`, but the factorial function scipy offers will still `inf` out at large argument.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to generate Poisson numbers as generating packet time in the network. How can i use this function for generating a Poisson number each continually?

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error trying to do division with very large numbers, use the floor division operator(`//`) instead of `/`.

`/` always returns a `float` whether or not the quotient is a whole number, but `//` will always return an `int` because it ignores any remainder.

Floor division works well when you only need the nearest whole number, or when you know that there will be no remainder.

For example:

```py
n = 5479174226627386185132548618631889901184058567721039026663537776859958572142823922154018004124214331284656070023110969954188349772902119804704702598117413535893235324950786546151906304553125886840777572957470085282511148870434624033780058878942475280220905204940912590689793763351716319910433886468914385951305420981218341758360474092776301397873143398400716102216234362319599979129849103060426402698870872632043715074191472826989513693244855131547410762874345810755472991691149113189232066769661520546071424890254793363936991126744220856839621014660137423821784120362098968560498064575399109509809144075148032776900847515603985610957107880554355044275212955190073519527570422912054125513731742317779855206190407418289517246109264745652852110081421227227070961742013273408514723195685741381697286381613758857699193539587512284537797999746347217299424379359513750952221691770954364716137930556670199833832758082670990435174217159016818867385870452581971005123842835195274660590963683055276508447399891075634175690730834545095637653926683291205950640671169613344094321183481673015248807254721861961606825265236717120630995029306863300152797740979622723077992597531418730154060586722026762649940060327662106126471869300626956821351541276596745066988430327015357076633723108282682951496900104227774031265608955533139148284989331915052933624499658651051440828202238489960326767828269045239036246524560280599359429362948869990238325225414863546810033093049656312737083470849175724716280988160656752494507880308537719866213986281428744395701992495890900685006572556038647427947211000473774809669487947261242971504873560862774351759068398609198938063648190986411623475678601785762035198084851677024720418537109078696439281976199801473556400242587983954277326038907443266131383984144369164421859162116568291430549701757135817698503903004323670868472322098027272184621482168087031650528289698350186047041813000034365448608048428773660686833199312751498967864183755218605831200984734033178462911134687785324823763323028015552729641117736966587793077203826296036041919194725026292750532442085716784596992382527663553269382473454979408093249648685286746030229491081455014614036595064858640568694698486979304728018771546672574024918565616067368338166156732338857331627951808169957419646902230036338741999953636036848632388844148127317892455668907319296843822473855127548875966047711681567056047142200887652753813947766711904166025820768269034575968052119510503904027778183601434729384390496315574344178298921662230866717650218116213036528198477594125535378602905735898504877520174927689474709976093921901862335223731814101741854177482601528306067859536805771591038922076905431603327032115233190666894167725361120047719134862842475859620392485715336420653304556079280724582370679687097844646877141209557539992623586632733333757970772758010549948610992979279029728363939092740579103618926669219471007734885307035386951609417262492554868268269616601555317177098129073353194374818770380635286890143608518924421556937379652833811709922933535682467614307592250619010586908268258080894148787717354387660022563306126433196292155158692150378675047252139601642814517370404428943577553004710999041554686557359791855943269834124640464693626652005988300338967392066239532981003255609078688925846590550467734155623629681262423331018717094741382157740779203008752310807956601087650996558858762789654321362720766176441413026718299435000087843048352098779842582683343460060362948117211949633698490613691410568825978953300376848779528540637469856488967807293836747161816004817653656673962008997810605012877379655141001116834025783685768201503435029018375437319930124960810208705813192640556535800129029066957647413650553915827395477280121732521449721923559779963923510646372389370353922598568377127428196541696965429553407721148989373822271488


divisor = 2

if n % divisor == 0:
    # We know the number is evenly divisible by the divisor, so we can use // without losing any possible remainder
    quotient = n // divisor  # This will work just fine

# This line will give an error since / always returns a float
quotient = n / divisor
# OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```