# Python3: long int too large to convert to float

Tags: python-3.x

I've been checking some topics around here about the same problem I'm getting but they don't seem to help.

My problem is when I try to execute the following code, I get the error found in the title. How do I go around this?

```
 d=2
 while(n != 1):        
        n = 2
        d = (math.sqrt(2 + d))
        n= (n/d)
        f = (f * (n))
 print (f)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python)

Comment: If you execute that code, you get "NameError: name 'n' is not defined".  What code are you actually executing?

Comment: Oops. I missed the value of n=2 above d=2.

Answer (score 3):

That's because math.sqrt, as a consequence of using the C sqrt function, works on floating point number which are not unlimited in size. Python is unable to convert the long integer into a floating point number because it is to big.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python) on ways to square root large integers.

Better, you could use the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which is an unlimited size number type stored in base-10. Use `decimal.Decimal(number).sqrt()` to find the sqrt of a number.

Comment: But, how do I precise exactly that I want my number to 2 d.p?

Comment: @Sab I don't understand. What does d.p. stand for? Decimal place? By default, decimal has 38 decimal places so the sqrt will be accurate upto 38 decimal places.

Comment: Ya, decimal places. Let's say math.srqt(2) gives a long number(it's irrational), therefore I get the error. So how do I use the decimal module to make it calculate to only 2decimal places, thus avoiding the error?

Comment: My answer has the proper code using decimal; no need to use that workaround.

Comment: I'm having an error though. [<class 'decimal.Overflow'>]

Comment: @Sab Looks like I was wrong about decimal; please use the methods in the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390807/integer-square-root-in-python). (the link is also in the answer).

Comment: What about cube root?