# Python : overflow error long int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, math, pow

I had to compute 2 to the power of 8635. I came across this error when i was computing 2^8635. Any suggestion how to solve this in python. Using Decimal module also didn't help.

```
math.exp(2**8635)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    long(math.exp(2**8635))
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to compute 2 to the power of 8635, or e to the power of 2 to the power of 8635?

Comment: @KobiK: try `decimal.Decimal(math.e) ** 2 ** 8635`. It also overflows. None of the other answers to that question are applicable at all.

Comment: What does `sys.float_info` output on your system?

Comment: Even `numpy.longdouble` isn't working for me.

Comment: If you just want 2 to the power of 8635, you can do `2**8635` or `pow(2, 8635)`. `math.exp(x)` calculates the natural exponential function, `e**x`, where e ≈ 2.718281828

Comment: `exp(2**8635)` is rather large: there are 2600 digits in its base 10 logarithm. IOW, just to write the _number of digits_ in `exp(2**8635)` takes a 2600 digit number.

Answer (score 7):

You can calculate `exp(2**8635)` using the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) arbitrary precision mathematics module:

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.exp(2**mp.mpf(8635))
```

The result is rather large, even in scientific notation, so I did a little bit of string processing on it, by copy & pasting the exponent into a string `s` and then reformatting it with:

```
>>> ' '.join([''.join(b) for b in zip(*[iter(s)]*10)])
```

The result, using a precision of `mp.dps=20` is

> 4.2745087809955028863988E+ 1075961842 0748495519 2355783856 9202899773 
>   5836295555 7242537851 6693465178 9188332936 7912863215 8269919370
>   9351573282 2091597135 7873818954 8423038425 5471700446 0909815025
>   4915349824 6380686906 6065142412 7999166978 5222679350 6349971415
>   2079241766 6069616716 5214806906 8965805654 9049342395 4257087497
>   9202056938 3115899033 9617474292 7677302965 5753590474 3880492978
>   3310677063 3380119492 7251778893 3532333942 0392908196 6724211094
>   8421111629 7159351144 1795137181 2264799291 0856206603 1305457648
>   0092179442 8275386674 9796135348 4212345607 2596906933 7416259320
>   1466097812 2578572779 3349115312 8876785712 0147507083 6261226991
>   0422767260 2197316370 2566751899 4709067324 2810166509 7120800169
>   7485704027 5902848998 8322436088 0980908767 3758921061 0035161163
>   7079806523 1330002249 6901129466 0981598858 6254175013 7068344219
>   8144416569 4188190080 3725722501 2061326523 2288670566 9409102206
>   8066363145 9074202764 8831634730 7112255017 0796958442 3491574250
>   3284769002 8003076564 8628481483 0439060173 9895022099 1254178687
>   3665797407 1814255571 0142720172 8605229862 9458410467 4672777325
>   9445377886 5938198959 1752282268 4759702578 8305033658 4673474227
>   0701134707 7350267519 5446056950 6855231007 2274227123 3745529068
>   2622945712 5542911110 4405852782 0415855498 0153628764 5474618275
>   7401652756 8947182158 7839446628 2805776521 9227970761 2076840252
>   6317298197 2928759787 3166056075 4718446805 4085909927 3696546013
>   4104199677 6666307004 0490874208 2916409726 3519895965 9647475416
>   4225305349 6334839659 5665063673 3375427908 5570705561 0968733246
>   7656866381 6185956211 6475910345 4507247539 2187977091 2735607271
>   0209770526 5707982249 7378999875 8729821041 8908550791 3750558609
>   2896112135 9430559215 0044675914 5643599469 1254786634 5242493728
>   3502270440 3874100770 4799209491 3826434565 6967844371 7035989909
>   7698785578 9911981690 6907193705 6149599295 7385801544 7008446783
>   4130808551 5517628873 4403074667 6152264003 5246435484 0092524145
>   7903102870 5636975728 9853241717 1112914752 3204974235 3214176498
>   6118461362 7598845054 2855525271 2496489615 8680550278 4583386686
>   7070831392 2705583569 2224816732 3325036729 8106736491 3995562245
>   2081730125 0118717575 0946706166 8838482200 0110510511 5193674369
>   7359353196 7070446633 3514990982 6428484539 3692837968 6448096531
>   0406301917 5207050949 5578924420 0588400753 2802517808 1953501443
>   3445927237 8496133188 6299359291 6240744112 8041383838 2523556917
>   1966060664 8100342007 9597089073 1150067540 7733669287 2770028938
>   5557716323 9545436149 8913712891 0452403558 6380308865 8375826610
>   3861873050 5349593724 7443661231 6344789431 9248320333 3901279921
>   2985101147 6464375714 1302826973 5468251818 0411981792 4830271478
>   1578285904 7739571097 8513979667 0471302144 9500998430 2500602635
>   1255157768 2597448484 2711867118 3605984621 3175011866 9369283240
>   7857863664 6903750271 5353454119 0302118673