# python count no of digits in a non negative integer

Tags: python

I am writing a program for counting number of digits in a non negative integer whose upper bound is 10^{1000000} and has a time limit of 12 seconds
I have declared an array with size 1000000 and the indexes 0,1,2...,1000000 correspond to the number of digits of the number represented by 10^{array index}.
However I am getting Time Limit Exceeded for input ranges close to 10^{10000}.
Please find inline the code for the same:

```
def Number(x):
    a=[0]*(1000000)
    for j in xrange(len(a)):
        #print j
        a[j]=j+1
    i=0
    flag=0
    flagc=0
    counter=0
    while(i<len(a)-1):
        #print x
        if (10**i)==x:
            print a[i]
            flag=1
            break
        elif x>(10**i) and x<(10**(i+1)):
            print a[i]
            flag=1
            break
        i=i+1

    if (i==len(a)-1 and flag==0 and x==(10**i)):
        print a[i]

number=int(input())
Number(number+1)
```

Please help as to how to handle large input values for the above as time limit got exceeded is coming for inputs close to 10^10000

Comment: Why not simply `len(str(x))`?

Comment: That is very slow @JohnColeman

Comment: `int(math.log10(n))+1`

Comment: I tried the log approach but it works well for a number having 15 digits.

Comment: It looks like you're already receiving input in decimal. Why not just return the length of the decimal input string you receive?

Comment: why not `len(input())`?

Comment: It is slow if we are converting our input to string and then computing its length.

Comment: Why does the math.log10 approach not work sumeet?

Comment: Your input is *already* string -- that's how the `input` function returns it.  Your main code takes the time to convert it to `int`.

Comment: @d_kennetz for math.log10 it is working till number having 15 digits

Comment: You need to add 1 to all log 10 values, it works with 15 digits

Comment: but the input in the question has a upper bound number of 1000001 digits

Comment: `int(math.log10(10**1000001))` returns `1000001`

Comment: Yeah, this solution is mathematically sound regardless of the number of digits of the input.

Comment: @d_kennetz Floats aren't precise enough with numbers this big `log10(10 ** 10000)` is equal to `log10(10 ** 10000 - 1)` even though those numbers have different numbers of digits.

Comment: try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python

Comment: I see what you are saying. It would have 1 less but it is calling them as equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP has stated in a comment that his problem is he needs to take a numerical input in the form of a string, add 1 to it, and return the number of digits.

Adding 1 to a number will change the number of digits IF AND ONLY IF the string is composed completely of `9`s. A simple test can achieve this. If it is all `9`s, output the string length plus 1, otherwise output the unchanged string length.

```
num = input()
length = len(num)
if num == '9' * length: # checks if string is all 9's
    print(length + 1)
else:
    print(length)
```

By eliminating the need to convert to `int` and back, we save a *lot* of time. This code executes in fractions of a second.

Comment: Thanks for the help the submission passed successfully

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this in pure python is to use `len(number)` where "number" has the required base.

Answer (score 0):

As shown above in the comments, `math.log10` is not accurate enough for large numbers. Try a `while` loop:

```
n = 10 ** 10000 - 1
count = 0
while n > 0:
    n //= 10
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Output:

```
10000
```

Changing `n` to `10 ** 10000` outputs `10001` as expected.

**EDIT:** I found something very surprising (to me, at least):

```
len(str(n))
```

is actually EXTREMELY fast! I tested for numbers up to 10^1000000, and it finishes executing in a matter of seconds!

Comment: i tried this method but when i change the value of n to 10**100000 am getting time limit exceeded

Comment: I just tried with 6 zeros (your program requirement), finished with the correct result in about 8 minutes.

Comment: Actually the problem has time limit as 12 seconds

Comment: Well, you should have at least specified that in your question. Let's see what I can find...

Comment: @SumeettenDoeschate See my edited answer, apparently the "slow" method isn't that shabby!

Comment: am getting time limit exceeded for a particular test case

Comment: It depends on the computer it is being run on.

Comment: i am submitting the program on online judge platform there a test case is getting time limit exceeded error

Comment: Could you link the website you are submitting to ?

Comment: If you are taking input as a string, **it is a total waste of time to convert it into an int and back.** Please confirm that you are indeed taking an `int` as the input, as in your code you are doing `int(input())`. If you are actually taking a string, just use `len(input())` and all of your problems will be solved in one line.

Comment: Actually 1 has to be added after taking the input so am converting it to int first

Comment: In that case, I have a completely different approach that does not require you to convert it to an `int`. I will post in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help the submission passed successfully

Answer (score 0):

To the commenters saying that this is an integer, the data being discussed in this question would overflow an integer, and these numbers would have to be represented as a strings in memory due to their length.

Comment: In Python 3, `int`s are unbounded by size.