# sine function in Python as Taylor Series Approximation

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am trying to implement sine function as Taylor Series approximation. I can't get a reasonable result with Taylor Series approximation form. I don't understand why.

Result is:
[image: sine with Taylor Series Approximation]

and my code in Python is here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import functools
f_reduce = functools.reduce

pow = np.power

from math import factorial

def f(t):
    return 2*t + np.pi / 2

# sine function in Taylor series form
def t_sin(t):
    def inner(n):
        return pow(-1, n) * pow(t, 2*n + 1) / factorial(2*n + 1)
    return f_reduce( lambda x,y: x + y, [ inner(step) for step in range(80) ] )

time = np.arange(-10*np.pi, 10 * np.pi, 0.1)
# x = np.sin(f(time))
x = t_sin(f(time))

plt.plot(time, x)
plt.show()
```

What's wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the plot look like if you limit the y axis to reasonable values?

Comment: @mkrieger1 According to formula, it should has to go until infinity. But factorial results become very big after a point (https://stackoverflow.com/q/16174399/6013366). So I chose 80 as the highest number, considering it as infinity :))

Comment: and formula can be seen here http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Comment: Well for `n` = 80 you are already calculating `factorial(161)`. Maybe you should start with `n` = 1, 2, 3, etc. and see what happens.

Comment: @mkrieger1 sine is a periodical function, so, whether we limit it or not, it should give same results for two points apart from each other with a constant time (period, 2*pi for sine), something similar to above plot (the one with Euler formula)

Comment: Please try it first before dismissing it. You're not plotting `sin`, you're plotting a sum of polynomials which *approximate* a sine curve for x values *close to 0*. For x values away from 0, the curve deviates from a sine curve considerably. You're expecting y values from -1 to 1, so you're not going to see anything if the plot range goes to 1e11.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right, actually everyting was correct. I am sorry for seen like dismissing, I was trying it actually but just wrote comment before trying. I am really sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkrieger , there were no problem with function but ranges were very stupid. Now, it actually looks like this:

[image]

Thank you @mkrieger ! :))

Comment: I bet it looks even better for much smaller `n`.  Looks more like numeric overflow issues rather than Taylor series deviating from real sine curve.

Comment: :D yeah, I agree :)) how can I choose your answer as "answer"? Is there a such option?

Comment: So, do you suppose to delete question or shall I do something for question?