# Math expression OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Tags: python

Im trying to code a formula to calculate a theoretical delay on a ethernet network over 2000 users. I've some static declared variables, but i'm having an OverflowError due to the operation values. Any idea to solve this? Any guidance will be appreciated.

[image]

```py
tp =0.87*10**-7
ti = 0.819*10**-3
c = 2
tg = 96/(1*10**7)
x_2 = ti**2
Et , Bt, Ew= [], [], [] 
for i in range(0,2000):
  lambdaa = i*2
  ro = lambdaa*(ti/2)
  Ew = (lambdaa*(x_2)/4*(1-ro))
  Bt = (tp/2)*(sum([2**(i-1)]))
  Et = (tp + ti + Ew +(c*(ti+tg+2*tp))+ Bt )
```

Traceback:

```
---> 12   Bt = (tp/2)*(sum([2**(i-1)]))
     13   Et = (tp + ti + Ew + Bt +(c*(ti+tg+2*tp)))
     14 

OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174399/overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-float-in-python)

Comment: How much precision do you need?

Comment: @Luke Theoretically at least, Et has to have values between `10^-4` or `10^-5`

Comment: 1) `sum([2**(i-1)])` is equal to `2**(i-1)`, you didn't implement the summation right. In fact, that sum of powers of 2 can be simplified to `2**i - 1`. 2) The error happens when you multiply a `float` `tp/2` by a HUGE integer `2**(i-1)`. In the extreme case, you have `2**1999`. Python's `float` is a 64-bit value with 11 bits for an exponent of 2. Those 11 bits only go from −1022 to +1023. You would need to use a different data type capable of representing bigger numbers, or you would have to change how you represent the data. For example, `(2, 1999)` can represent `2**1999` with less data.